# Is there a way to compile or port eclipse projects into a MIDlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-me

i'm making a small test shoot-em-up for my nokia and i've already made the content for it. Is there a way to compile or port Eclipse projects into a Midlet, and if there is, how do i do that?

This is just for a nokia s40 phone that i have in my house, i tried downloading the S40 SDK but i got Mail.ru adware instead and i had to use system restore to get rid of it.

```java
//this is just a section of the game's code. there's a lot more.
//variables
    double counter = 0;
    double thing = 0;
    double thing2 = 0;
    double epic = 1;
    double epic2 = 1;
    double phase = 0;
    double div = 60/1000000000;
//the attack
    private void attack1()
    {
        //bullet spread
        float n = 4f;
        if(counter % 1200 == 0 && counter > 10000)
        {
            //circles
            for(float i = 0; i<360; i+= 360/5)
            {
                for(float j = -n; j < n+1; j++)
                 c.addBullet(new Bullet(WIDTH/2, 60, (1200/1.3)*counter+i+5*j, 0.03+0.003*((double)n-Math.abs(j)), 13, 13, 13, 13, 0, 0, this));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using anything specific from Nokia you could develop using a Java ME SDK.

My personal take is version 2.5.2. You can download it at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#sun_java_wireless_toolkit-2.5.2_01b-oth-JPR